# Sorting nomenclature alphabetically

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I would like to sort the attached nomenclature alphabetically while considering the following items:

1. Some of the items are bold. I want to sort irrespective of a symbol being bold.
2. Symbols like J_c should precede J_R.
3. If I change the current format to one-column, it exceeds one page. I wonder if it is possible to have the nomenclature in two continuous pages.

Thanks

[image]

```
% Latin [0]
\nomenclature[0]{$\bm{t}$}{Traction vector}
\nomenclature[0]{$\bm{n}$}{Normal vector}
\nomenclature[0]{$S$}{Integration domain for J-integral}
\nomenclature[0]{$a_0$}{Existing crack length}
\nomenclature[0]{$B$}{Width}
\nomenclature[0]{$W$}{Strain energy density}
\nomenclature[0]{$J$}{J-integral}
\nomenclature[0]{$J_R$}{Fracture resistance}
\nomenclature[0]{$M$}{Moment}
\nomenclature[0]{$H$}{Height}
\nomenclature[0]{$\bm{x}_i$}{Global coordinate system ($i=1,2,3$)}
\nomenclature[0]{$\bm{X}_i$}{Cohesive element coordinate system ($i=1,2,3$)}
\nomenclature[0]{$L$}{Length}
\nomenclature[0]{$t_c$}{Cohesive strength/Peak traction}
\nomenclature[0]{$\bm{u}$}{Displacement vector}
\nomenclature[0]{$J_{ss}$}{Steady-state fracture resistance}
\nomenclature[0]{$I$}{Second moment of area}
\nomenclature[0]{$L_c$}{Length of cohesive zone}
\nomenclature[0]{$G_{12}$}{In-plane shear modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$G_{23}$}{Out-of-plane shear modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$G_{13}$}{Out-of-plane shear modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$J_c$}{Fracture energy per unit area of the cohesive law}
\nomenclature[0]{$h_c$}{Cohesive element thickness}
\nomenclature[0]{$E$}{Young's modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$E_{11}$}{Longitudinal Young’s modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$E_{22}$}{Transverse Young’s modulus}
\nomenclature[0]{$E_{33}$}{Transverse Young’s modulus}


% Greek [1]
\nomenclature[1]{$\Gamma$}{Integral path for J-integral}
\nomenclature[1]{$\bm{\sigma_{ij}}$}{Stress tensor}
\nomenclature[1]{$\bm{\epsilon_{ij}}$}{Strain tensor}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta_c$}{Critical opening}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta^*$}{End-opening}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta_t^*$}{Tearing end-opening (corresponding to mode III)}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta_s^*$}{Sliding end-opening (corresponding to mode II)}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta_n^*$}{Normal end-opening (corresponding to mode I)}
\nomenclature[1]{$\delta_e$}{Elastic end-opening}
\nomenclature[1]{$\theta$}{Rotation}
\nomenclature[1]{$\nu_{12}$}{In-plane Poisson’s ratio}
\nomenclature[1]{$\nu_{23}$}{Out-of-plane Poisson’s ratio}
\nomenclature[1]{$\nu_{13}$}{Out-of-plane Poisson’s ratio}
\nomenclature[1]{$\sigma_{b}$}{Bending stress}
```